# Can't SOAP compressed PHP output

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Hi everybody (please excuse syntax faults, not yet fluent english),

I'm having trouble getting my SOAPs streams compressed : either I'm having a "Can't uncompress compressed response" or "looks like we got no XML document" error.

I'm using PHP 5.3.3 Suhoshin and apache2 on a Debian.

I cannot debug deeply or snif/snort network frames since I'm working on a colleague's app in which the client and the server are both remote.

So, I tried the following :

- php.ini output compression handler

  - ob_gzhandler (fail)
  - zlib.output_handler (fail)
- soap options (all failed)

  - SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE | 5 (from there : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47925)
  - the same without the '| 5'
  - replacing SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE by SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP

Comment: Tried to add 'content-encoding' => 'gzip' to the options, seems to do nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Is zlib enabled on your install of php?

I'm having similar trouble. I have 2 systems, one where it work, and one where it doesn't.

On the one that works, if I call phpinfo() I get

---

```
Configure Command =>  …(lots of stuff)… '--enable-zip' …(more stuff)…
```

and later on

```
zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter support => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.5
Linked Version => 1.2.5
```

---

But on the one that doesn't work, the '--enable-zip' was not there, and there is no zlib section.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, zlib is enabled, but it seems that both client and server don't handle it the same way (since they are configured identically on this point). The client and the server are on the same machine (yes, I know...), and run in the same Apache/PHP engine.

Comment: Problem not solved, but we now use another mean to transfer data (simply echo JSON). Thanks Colin :)